# Paypal - Sandbox - Open Test Account

Tags: paypal

After X hours of searching and lost-ing inside documentation and this community, I understand that, if :

- I'm non US developer
- my client is not a US company
- I want integrate Paypal in market-place
- sending several emails to Paypal support

I need to:

- register as Business Account US in paypal.com ( and not in sandbox )
- find an US user because I'm not, otherwise I need to fake my address, zip code and state
- enter in developer.paypal.com

Someone can answer me YES ? or the right procedure ?

Thanks

Comment: I find some help here ( https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ )

Answer (score 0):

from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#international-developer-questions

"I'm a non-U.S. developer. What products are available to me?

The REST API supports a number of countries and currencies. The REST API provides simple payment processing for common business needs, including PayPal payments, direct credit card payments, authorization and capture, and refunds. For more advanced payment solutions such as parallel and recurring payments, you can use the NVP/SOAP APIs.

If you've previously used our NVP/SOAP APIs, you can continue to use them. Using your old Sandbox email address and password, you can import existing Sandbox accounts on the Sandbox Accounts page."

I started on this page:
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/